# Is AndroidManifest necessary after app installation

Tags: installation, native-library

As I understand during app installation the Java dex code is converted to native code (oat)
which is basically native .so library.

Is the manifest file still needed/used after that, or not?
Can you point me to android code that loads this library, or makes it if it is not present in cache?